# Cannot build Dapper by myself, some strange errors issue related to SDK?

Tags: c#, build, dapper

I would like to build Dapper by myself so that I can modify it a bit (or at least finding out if there is any way to inject some kind of `parameters conversion` such as to convert `bool` properties to `int` in some specific cases).

However looks like there is some magic advanced thing used in `Dapper` that I've never known of, I'm pretty sure that I've already had .NET Core 1.1, .NET Core 2.1, .NET Core 2.2 and all released versions of .NET Standard (SDKs) installed. But still the following error is shown after trying to build the whole solution:

> The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET Core 2.1.  Either target .NET Core 1.1 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK that supports .NET Core 2.1

Actually there are total 9 errors, as in the following screenshot:

[image]

I'm never encountered this kind of advanced scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You need to download and install the latest Net Core SDK and make sure the projects point to a Net Core version you have installed. The problem should disappear then. I've literally had the same problem countless times now with projects - theres some sort of (I dont wanna say bug), but, issue with some of the versions and the way the projects get resolved - dont ask why, there just is

Comment: what do you mean by the `latest Net core SDK`? I have version 2.2, is that not even enough? The latest is in preview (3.0). Also how to make sure the projects point to a specific .NET Core version? I always set the `Target Framework` in project's properties window, but for `Dapper` that cannot be set because it targets multiple frameworks (can only be set in the project file).